# Doxygen comments for variant C functions with similar signatures

Tags: c, doxygen, c99

I'm writing a program in C. Due to the language's static typing, Its necessary to duplicate functions in the following way:

```
void foo_8(uint8_t thingy);
void foo_16(uint16_t thingy);
void foo_32(uint32_t thingy);
```

When it comes to doxygen comments, you're forced to copy-paste the same comment block several times. Does doxygen have facilities/tags to say "This function is the same as another focuntion"?

Comment: Declaraing functions with same names and different signatures is [not allowed in C](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0fBkMCLImY8pzGO5).

Comment: That's a mistake. I'll fix the original question.

Comment: C is not strongly typed. Use a amcro and `_Generic`.

Comment: In case you missed Olaf's meaning there, [C has evolved](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic): `#define foo( thingy ) _Generic( ( thingy ), uint8_t: foo_8, uint16_t: foo_16, default: foo_32 )( thingy )` -- you can then just call it as `foo( thingy )` and have the macro figure out the actual function to call. @Olaf: That allows OP to *call* the function generically, but his question was about *documenting* each of the three function, which `_Generic` does not help with (as the three functions are still there, and would benefit from documentation).

Comment: @DevSolar: Not quite right: Depending on the complexity, you can already implement the functionality in the macro (just suitable for small functions). Even iff you use seperate functions, it is sufficient to only doxygen the macro. You just call that macro and leave the functions semantically "private" to the implementation - in terms of the documentation only, of course. Each function can just reference the macro, e.g. with `\sa`.

Comment: @DevSolar: Unfortunately, we're using C99 so that syntactical sugar doesn't exist. Otherwise, it would be nice to do.

Comment: @MarkP: You should use the appropriate tag then if you cannot use standard C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`copydoc`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc), [`copybrief`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopybrief) or [`copydetails`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydetails) :

```
  \copydoc foo_8()
```

or

```
  \brief \copybrief foo_8()
  \details \copydetails foo_8()
```